# Looking for a Git GUI which displays GitFlow properly

Tags: data-visualization, git

In the educational materials, GitFlow tree looks like this:

http://research.agmip.org/download/attachments/1212609/image2013-4-17+10%3A47%3A36.png?version=1&modificationDate=1366210080942

In reality, using any Git GUI, it looks way messy (image is taken from a random site):

[image]

My question: is there any Git GUI which displays gitflow-compliant tree as it's displayed in educational materials? Master branch at the right, develop branch at the middle etc.?

Comment: Why not fix the educational materials?

Comment: Educational materials looks pretty, branches are well-organized. I like them. That's how real GIT tools should look like.

Comment: I disagree that they're "pretty".   I think they follow the intentionally sloppy aesthetic that's popular these days, trying to look like something drawn with a crayon on a paper placemat.   Very "hip".  Personally, I like the way the actual git guis do it; from left to right, clean and crisp.   Plus the layout won't go to garbage as quickly if the commit comments are long.  But it's your request.  Good luck with it.

Comment: I am not talking about hipster styling of nodes and edges, it's the "whatever" category. Commit comments should be placed *smart* way :)

Comment: Right.  "Smart", as in "the way people read things".   Like left to right.  Master on left, branches on right.  And again, good luck.

Comment: Your first link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Try

[GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/git-client) - The legendary Git GUI for Windows, Mac and Linux

It supports Visual Commit History.

[image]